# sort by Property that's not part of the GroupBy statement

Tags: gremlin, amazon-neptune

I have a graph with one start-node and two goal-vetices. Two paths lead to the first goal, another path to the second.
I look for all paths to the goals vertices and collect the edge weights (sack(sum)). I add the sum of all paths leading to the same goal via group().by().

query so far:

```
g.withSack(1.0f).V('v0')
    .repeat(
        outE().sack(mult).by('weight')
        .inV()
    ).until(hasLabel('goal'))
    .group().by().by(sack())
    .unfold()
    .project('sack', 'map')
        .by(select(values))
        .by(select(keys).valueMap(true))
    .order().by('sack', desc)
```

the result looks like this:

```
{'sack': 0.27999999999999997, 'map': {<T.id: 1>: 'v7', <T.label: 4>: 'goal', 'date': ['02-02-2022']}}
{'sack': 0.125, 'map': {<T.id: 1>: 'v3', <T.label: 4>: 'goal', 'date': ['02-02-2022']}}
```

**now I want to also sort by date... However, using by('date', desc) results in an error:

"java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable"

can I somehow access the date-value inside the map? or sort by date in some other way?**

(fyi: by(sack(), desc) works just as well as by('sack', desc) )

data:

```
g.addV('start').property(id, 'v0')
  .addV('road').property(id, 'v1')
  .addV('road').property(id, 'v2')
  .addV('goal').property(id, 'v3').property('date', '02-02-2022')
  .addV('road').property(id, 'v4').
  .addV('road').property(id, 'v5').
  .addV('road').property(id, 'v6').
  .addV('goal').property(id, 'v7').property('date', '22-02-2022')
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.4).from(V('v0')).to(V('v1'))
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.4).from(V('v1')).to(V('v2'))
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.4).from(V('v2')).to(V('v3'))
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.5).from(V('v0')).to(V('v5'))
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.5).from(V('v5')).to(V('v4'))
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.5).from(V('v4')).to(V('v3'))
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.7).from(V('v0')).to(V('v6'))
  .addE('link').property('weight', 0.4).from(V('v6')).to(V('v7'))
```

(my code runs on Neptune with 'gremlin': {'version': 'tinkerpop-3.4.11'})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to select the `date` key from the `map` map.

```java
gremlin> g.withSack(1.0f).
......1>   V('v0').
......2>   repeat(outE().sack(mult).by('weight').inV()).
......3>   until(hasLabel('goal')).
......4>   group().by().by(sack()).
......5>   unfold().
......6>   project('sack', 'map').
......7>     by(select(values)).
......8>     by(select(keys).valueMap(true)).
......9>   order().by('sack', desc).by(select('map').select('date'),desc)

==>[sack:0.280,map:[id:v7,label:goal,date:[22-02-2022]]]
==>[sack:0.1250,map:[id:v3,label:goal,date:[02-02-2022]]]
```

Note however, for the dates to sort properly (if you encode them as strings), you should use something close to ISO 8601 form, such as `YYYY-MM-DD` or more concretely,  `2022-02-22`. It might be more efficient to store actual dates, or epoch offset integers.

**UPDATED based on comment thread 2022-02-23**

OK, I think I figured out what you are seeing - I was testing using the Gremlin Console at the 3.5.2 level and it looks like you are using Amazon Neptune. Neptune is currently at the 3.4.11 level (but should be moving up to the 3.5.2 level fairly soon). Here is the modified query running at the TinkerPop 3.5.2 level.

```java
gremlin> g.withSack(1.0f).
......1>   V('v0').
......2>   repeat(outE().sack(mult).by('weight').inV()).
......3>   until(hasLabel('goal')).
......4>   group().by().by(sack()).
......5>   unfold().
......6>   project('sack', 'map').
......7>     by(select(values)).
......8>     by(select(keys).valueMap(true)).
......9>   order().
.....10>     by(select('map').select('date').unfold(),asc)  

==>[sack:0.1250,map:[id:v3,label:goal,date:[2022-02-02]]]
==>[sack:0.280,map:[id:v7,label:goal,date:[2022-02-22]]]
```

Comment: getting closer, but now the error is 'java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable' (I only ever get the errors, when this sorting is the only one, so for testing I always remove the by('sack') )

Comment: As to the date, you are right of course. In my real data, the format is datetime('2020-02-02T00:00:00')

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "getting closer" - I ran that query using your data.

Comment: me too, but I only get the error when running the sorting with only the date part:
`.order().by(select('map').select('date'),desc)`
It makes sense though, as the attribute date in the valueMap is an array: 'date': ['22-02-2022']

Comment: The answer to 'java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable' is:
        `.by(select('map').select('date').limit(1).unfold(),desc)`
        in my case `limit(1)` is not strictly necessary, but it prevents later errors, by simply choosing one date, if there are several. `unfold()` unpacks the array to the single value in it, giving as a string/date/... which is again comparable

Comment: I’ll take a look at that, but I based my answer off your original question which includes the sack in the ordering.  It should be fine to compare lists.  I know I have done it before in Gremlin.

Comment: OK I think I figured out what you are seeing - I was testing using the Gremlin Console at the 3.5.2 level and it looks like you are using Neptune. Neptune is currently at the 3.4.11 level (but should be moving up to the 3.5.2 level fairly soon). I'll update the answer.